# program giving me invalid syntax in else block

Tags: python, if-statement, database-connection

This is a small part of a code I am currently writing in python,
the system is giving me an invalid syntax error at 'p' of print in else block.

```
def bookticket():
        enteredname=name.get()
        enteredage=age.get()
        enteredgender=selectedgender.get()
        enteredtime=selectedtime.get()
        enteredfrom=selectedfrom.get()
        enteredto=selectedto.get()
        enteredemail=email.get()
        if (enteredname=="") or (enteredage=="") or (enteredemail==""):
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR","YOU SEEMED TO HAVE MISSED SOME DETAIL")
        else:
            entereddate=str(selecteddateday.get())+" "+selecteddatemonth.get()+"
"+selecteddateyear.get()
            ticketno=random.randrange(10000,99999)
            ticketnolabel=Label(book,text="YOUR TICKET NUMBER IS:\n"+str(ticketno),font=allfont).grid(row=5,column=6,columnspan=3)
            pleasenotelabel=Label(book,text="PLEASE MAKE NOTE OF TICKET
NUMBER",font=allfont).grid(row=6,column=6,columnspan=5)
            ticketcommand=("insert into details values ('"+enteredname+"','"+enteredage+"','"+enteredgender+"','"+enteredfrom+"','"+enteredto+"','"+entereddate+"','"+enteredtime+"','"+ticketprice+"','"+str(ticketno)+"','"+str(enteredemail+"');")
        
            print(ticketcommand)
            cursor.execute(ticketcommand)
            con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing `)` of `str(enteredemail)` is missing in the previous line.

```
ticketcommand=("insert into details values ('"+enteredname+"','"+enteredage+"','"+enteredgender+"','"+enteredfrom+"','"+enteredto+"','"+entereddate+"','"+enteredtime+"','"+ticketprice+"','"+str(ticketno)+"','"+str(enteredemail)+"');")
```